# Redirecting from one TLD to another

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains for a website (we're using Apache), `example.com` and `example.org`. The website responds to a wildcard subdomain for both of these. I want, however, to have the .com as the canonical domain. By that, I mean, I want to redirect (301) everything to the .com, but maintain the subdomain. For example.

```
example.org => example.com
sub.example.org => sub.example.com
```

I don't know enough about regular expressions to work out how to set this up. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias *.example.org
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?example\.org$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

..then have your other vhost (the one serving the content for example.com) configured with `ServerName example.com` and `ServerAlias *.example.com`.

Edit: made the matching of subdomains optional by adding the "?" quantifier

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. Even better, I think I understand how it works, too. I hate just copying and pasting stuff without actually comprehending what it's doing.

Comment: @EddMorgan Great!  Let me know if you'd like to see more explanation for the individual components of the config; this answer is kinda short on explanation by my standards, heh.